# angular js TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
habilitationCtrl.groupSort = function(g1, g2) {
   if (g1.nom.toLowerCase() < g2.nom.toLowerCase()) 
     return -1;
   else if (g1.nom.toLowerCase() == g2.nom.toLowerCase()) 
     return 0;
   else return 1;
}
```

I have this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: how are you calling this function ?

Comment: Well, it means that `g1`, `g2`, `g1.nom` or `g2.nom` are undefined. To debug, which is true, I recommend you to print them using `console.log(g1, g2);` immediately after you enter in the function. Otherwise, post a bit more of you code so we can help you, since we don't know what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: the function is called 
herehabilitationCtrl.setAllGroups = function(groups){
  if(groups){
   habilitationCtrl.allGroups=groups.sort(habilitationCtrl.groupSort);
   habilitationCtrl.refreshInactiveGroups();
  }

Comment: i need do instruction like if name is null or blank do nothing

Comment: It simply means you apply your function to undefined objects or to objects with undefined properties. If you could post a jsfiddle working example it would be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: @ Adrian Pop when I remove the function toLowerCase, the list is displayed but does not sort

Comment: Again, can you please, please, check if all of your objects have the `nom` property? Or maybe there is a undefined object in your list that is ruining everything. It's just a simple print and check.

Answer (score 0):

@BiginByHelloWord - Hey wrap your functionality inside an if statement, which checks if the g1,g2 ,g1.nom and g2.nom are not undefined.

If(g1 && g2 && g1.nom && g2.nom)

Comment: thank you all it's solved: 

if(typeof g1.name == 'undefined' || typeof g2.name == 'undefined')